# A Congruence problem to check divisibility...

Tags: divisibility

Prove that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $2^{2^{4n+1}}+7$ is always composite.

I compute the expression for n=1, and see that it is divisible by 11. So my natural guess is that $2^{2^{4n+1}}+7\equiv 0 \text{ mod } 11$. But I don't have any idea to proceed further. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your conjecture is correct, you should have
$$
2^{2^{4n+1}}\equiv4\pmod{11}
$$
that's the same as
$$
2^{2^{4n+1}-2}\equiv1\pmod{11}
$$
which is granted if you show that
$$
2^{4n+1}-2\equiv0\pmod{10}
$$
that is,
$$
16^n\equiv1\pmod{5}
$$
Fix a proof for every statement and you're done.